# Saving data to database in unit testing

Tags: laravel, unit-testing

Why it's impossible to create dummy data in unit testing like below?

```
DB::table('users')->insert([
[
'name' => 'test',
],
```

I saw that in order to create data you need to create factory, but when I try to insert data like this:

```
User::factory()->count(1)->create([
'name' => 'test'
]);
```

It also don't insert new data.
What is the easiest way to to that? Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No need for a factory, and you dont need to use DB if you a User model setup. Laravel is great for these types of things and I recommend reading the docs [here](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/)

For you problem its as simple as this

```
User::create(['name' => 'test']);
```

Comment: Ok, I see my problem was I used RefreshDatabase, so I wasn't able to see data in database..